# Meaning of ">" in MySQL update statement

Tags: mysql

First things first. I only know MS SQL Server. So, its hard to understand some MySQL syntax.
Below statement is in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO stats_by_variantstats(variant_id, count, nonzero, sum, avg, sumsq, wavg)
VALUES(5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        count = count + $count,
        nonzero = nonzero + ($value>0),
        sum = sum + $value,
        avg = sum / (count + 1),
        sumsq = sumsq + ($value * $value),
        wavg = 0.9 * wavg + 0.1 * $value
```

What is meaning of `($value>0)` in above statement (line: 5) for following cases:

1. $value = 0
2. $value = 1
3. $value = 10

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Value is greater than zero. It seems like you're trying to evaluate if value is a negative number

Comment: I am implementing Genetify Multivariate testing in Asp.Net using MSSQL. The $value can never be negative. Infact, i think it can't be zero also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Boolean expression. Its meaning is identical to this conditional expression:

```
CASE WHEN $value>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

In case of your `UPDATE`, the `nonzero` column will be incremented each time a `$value` is positive.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
($value>0)
```

Is a boolean expression in MySQL.  Boolean values are interpreted as 0 for false and 1 for true.  This is not true in all databases, but it is true in MySQL.

So, when $value is 0 then this is "0".  When 1 or 10, then it is "1".  The result is that the field `nonzero` is incremented when the value is greater than 0.

In other words, this is equivalent to:

```
nonzero = (case when $value > 0 then nonzero + 1 else nonzero end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If $value is greater than 0 (positive) it will count in "nonzero"  variable.  Each number will get a +1 for each positive number.

Comment: Did you mean if $value = 10, than 9 will be added?